# Use local network while VPN'd into another network

Tags: networking, vpn, dns

So I'm at work and I VPN into a remote network. Both networks have their own DNS servers that have hostnames that resolve to internal IP's. I've set it up in network manager so I can ping internal IP's on both networks (including the DNS servers) but I can't get DNS lookup on both networks simultaneously.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search company.com
nameserver 172.16.66.254
nameserver 192.168.0.6
nameserver 192.168.0.7
```

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit desktop.

Where `172.16.66.254` is the VPN DNS server and `192.168.0.6` and 7 are the local DNS servers. Will I need to run some sort of local dns server that pulls from both?

Edit:

```
dig -b 192.168.0.51 mylocalserver

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> -b 192.168.0.51 mylocalserver
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 42426
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mylocalserver.             IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.0.6#53(192.168.0.6)
;; WHEN: Thu Feb 23 14:01:40 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 23
```

Comment: I have a hunch as to what is happening, but to be certain I'll need to know what happens when you query a VPN hostname while the machine is setup to use the local DNS. (Or the other way around) post the output of `dig -b <localIP> <VPNHostname>`

Comment: @Huckle I've added the output of that command with one of the local hostnames that isn't working. But I think the problem is that the first dns server 172.16.66.254 says that the hostname doesn't exist so the second dns server (192.168.0.6) is never asked.

Comment: Indeed, so you've boiled your question down to: How can I use multiple DNS servers for queries? Turns out that isn't really possible (that I know of). So the alternate question is: How can I get one of the DNS servers to not return Not Found? The answer to that is to have the DNS server forward requests to other DNS servers before replying with Not Found.

Answer (score 2):

This comment may answer the question:

> Indeed, so you've boiled your question down to: How can I use multiple
>   DNS servers for queries? Turns out that isn't really possible (that I
>   know of). So the alternate question is: How can I get one of the DNS
>   servers to not return Not Found? The answer to that is to have the DNS
>   server forward requests to other DNS servers before replying with Not
>   Found.

– [Huckle](https://askubuntu.com/users/41418/huckle) [Feb 24 '12 at 22:59](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107072/use-local-network-while-vpnd-into-another-network/240920#comment125372_107072)